# Access - Is there a way to apply a filter via macro or VBA that does not overwrite existing filters?

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I have a form built that has a SQL builder "search box" in the header. This allows the user to select a location and/or a date range to filter the records by if they wish.

I want to provide the user with options to further filter the records by the time that the record was recorded (in this situation by a standard work shift). For example I want to retrieve all records that have a time between 7 am and 7 pm. I can do this manually on the form, but I would rather have a button that runs a macro or VBA code that performs this without having to manually enter the values.

I have a macro set up that is:

```
RunMenuCommand
      Command ApplyFilterSort
ApplyFilter
      Where Condition = ((TimeValue([qryDiversion_Review].[Transaction_Time]) Between #7:00:00 AM# And #6:59:59 PM#))
```

This works, but it clears out any other filters that may be in place, for example if the user used any of the options on the header to filter by facility or date range.

Is there a way I can add this filter without removing any existing ones? I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just append a filter to the existing one in VBA. You need to check if the filter is set, though.

```vb
Me.Filter = IIF(Nz(Me.Filter, "") = "", "", Me.Filter & " AND ") & "TimeValue([qryDiversion_Review].[Transaction_Time]) Between #7:00:00 AM# And #6:59:59 PM#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Note that this doesn't take existing filters into account, so you might get conflicting filters (e.g. if a filter selecting all times between 6 and 7 AM was already set)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I tried to use your code, but I'm getting a syntax error on the first line when I try to compile. It doesn't seem to like something around the word 'Between'. I tried adding parentheses around (TimeValue......PM#) but that isn't it. I'm unfortunately not versed well enough in VBA to figure it out.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot the quotes, fixed in current edit. Note that (at least for me), after learning just the basics VBA often is way easier to use than macros.

Comment: I appreciate your help Erik. I added your code and something is not working correctly. It could be other elements in the form for all I know. I have  a button set to clear all filters (a macro that runs the 'ApplyFilterSort' command). When that macro runs, the filters are removed, which is confirmed by the record count and the form showing that it is unfiltered. If I run the code though, it seems to be picking up on old filters that should have been "cleared" by the macro. Am I using the wrong command for the 'Clear' button possibly?